# ELSEIF statement with boolean output

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

Below is what I tried:

```
if (p_testing < 0.05):
    sig == True,
elif (p_testing > 0.05):
    sig == False
```

The output I am trying to have is either `False` or `True`. The error I am receiving is the following:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: ```sig = True``` A single equal to sign for assignment. And without a comma ```,```

Comment: What happened when you tried copying and pasting `the truth value of a Series is ambiguous` into a search engine?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you have given.

```
if (p_testing < 0.05):
    sig == True,
elif (p_testing > 0.05):
    sig == False
```

I can tell that you want to assign a `True` or `False` to `sig`.

`==` is for comparing

`=` is for assigning

And In your code, you are using a double equals to assign a value which is Cleary incorrect.

So change it up.

```
if (p_testing < 0.05):
    sig = True,
elif (p_testing > 0.05):
    sig = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, First of all, `==` or double equal to sign is for comparison. It is used in if statements to check : **is** `a` **equal to** `b`**?** or `a==b` . And a single equal to sign `=` is an assignment operator. `one_var=1` Here, 1 is assigned to `one_var`

Here is the corrected code.

```
if (p_testing < 0.05):
    sig = True
elif (p_testing > 0.05):
    sig =False
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it, since p_testing was a series, i had to specify what value in the series, the solution was as follows:

```
if (p_testing[0] < 0.05):
    sig = True
elif (p_testing[0] > 0.05):
    sig = False
```